# Why is my Spring Boot @Autowired MyBatis static mapper null?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mybatis

I have the following class, but Spring and MyBatis-Spring-Boot-Starter will not autowire my mapper.

When I run the request, I get the output from the `println()`

```
sourceMapper = null
```

#### Model

```
public class Source {       
    @Autowired
    public static SourceMapper sourceMapper;   #### Why isn't this set?

    public static Source findOrCreate(String url) {
        ...
        System.out.println("sourceMapper = " + sourceMapper);
        source = sourceMapper.findByHost(host);
        ...
    }

}
```

I followed the examples as closely as possible.

http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/

The other `@Autowired` `Mappers` in the main `@Controller` class that handles requests work, even though they are private.

This is the Mapper class

```
package ...mapper;

@Mapper
public interface SourceMapper {
  ...
```

---

I ran into this issue again with a new model and mapper. I tried to follow [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null) and [the code sample](https://github.com/chrylis/spring_autowired_npe_example/blob/working-configurable/spring-autowired-npe/src/main/java/com/chrylis/example/spring_autowired_npe/MileageFeeCalculator.java), but it was *still* null! I tried `@Configurable`, `@Service`, `@Component`.

`Model`

```
@Configurable
public class Domain {
    @Autowired
    private static DomainMapper domainMapper;

    public static void incrementCounter(String host) {
        ...
        Domain d = getDomainMapper().find(host, thisMonth);

    public static DomainMapper getDomainMapper() {
        return domainMapper;

    public static void setDomainMapper(DomainMapper domainMapper) {
        Domain.domainMapper = domainMapper;
```

`Mapper`

```
@Mapper
public interface DomainMapper {
```

MyBatis 3.4.5, MyBatis Spring 1.3.1, MyBatis Spring Boot Autoconfigure 1.3.1, MyBatis Spring Boot Starter 1.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it with

```
private static DomainMapper getDomainMapper() {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/52997701/148844
    if (domainMapper == null)
        domainMapper = MyApplication.getApplicationContext().getBean(DomainMapper.class);
    return domainMapper;
```

And

`MyApplication`

```
@Autowired // for AWS
private static ApplicationContext context;
// I believe this only runs during an embedded Tomcat with `mvn spring-boot:run`. 
// I don't believe it runs when deploying to Tomcat on AWS.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    context = SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
```

But I don't like it!

Comment: This doesn't work with unit tests and I don't think it works when deploying to Elastic Beanstalk Tomcat instance. It complains about `java.lang.NullPointerException` in `getDomainMapper()` ostensibly because `getApplicationContext()` is null.

Comment: I manually injected the `DomainMapper` from the `Controller` before I call the static function. I don't like this, but have no other choice (other than passing the `DomainMapper` as an argument).

Comment: Hello I'm facing this issue. What is "MyApplication" in this fix? Is there some dependency I need to use this object.

Answer (score 0):

Spring will only try to inject a bean for you if another bean requires it.

Your class `Source` is just a normal class with bunch of static methods.

Hence it's not under creation control of Spring.

If you want to inject `SourceMapper` to your `Source`, you should mark `Source` with `@Component` or `@Service` so that the container will know it should create a bean of `Source` type for you and give you an instance of `SourceMapper`.

Moreover, the `SourceMapper` should be declared non-static, to prevent if a class access the variable before injected. And static field can be injected only if it use field setter injection.

Comment: Is there a way to instantiate a `SourceMapper` manually? It is an interface and I don't know how it is/will be created by Spring/MyBatis. `public interface SourceMapper`. It doesn't make a lot of sense to create a `Source` bean first the way it is written, but I suppose I could re-write it if I had to.

Comment: You must declare your `Source` to become a component/ bean.

Comment: Add `@Component / @Service / @Repository` your `@Mapper` class dude

Comment: Not a dude. I added `@Autowired` instances in the entry `@Controller` class and passed them down into the static methods. It worked and `SourceMapper` is set but is jumping to `InvocableHandlerMethod` in the debugger when it tries to call `sourceMapper.findByHost(host)`. But that's for another question.

Comment: Your setup is very unusual. If you need help contact me, I can debug via teamview haha.

Comment: I encountered this problem again with a new model. I tagged the `Domain` model with `@Component` and I added getters/setters for the `DomainMapper`. I left it static because I only need one instance and it's accessed from a static `Domain.increment()`. However, it is still null, so this doesn't work. I also tried `@Configurable`.

Comment: Forget the static methods and classes. Only utility methods should be static. Use singleton beans instead. If you need a bean in a method then that method should be non-static. And then you can use the `@Autowired` annotation to inject that bean and if you annotate your class with `@Component` annotation then you can inject that class into each of your other classes where you want to use that method.